# Hide and Show Fab when Recycler scroll in Fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments

I have a fragment and it has Recyclerview and Fab. I want to do when recycler scrool, fab shown or hide this code is not working in onCreateView. (Code is working I tested in an activity but in fragment doesnt work)

```
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)
    
    hideFab()

    return view
```

}

```
private fun hideFab(){
    view?.rvHome?.addOnScrollListener(object : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener(){
        override fun onScrolled(recyclerView: RecyclerView, dx: Int, dy: Int) {
            if (dy<0&& view!!.fab.isShown){
                view!!.fab.show()
            }else if (dy>0&& view!!.fab.isShown){
                view!!.fab.hide()
            }

            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy)
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before `onCreateView` finished, `Fragment`'s view is still `null`, and scroll listener just not applied. So, there are two options:

1. you can pass inflated View to the `hideFab`:

```
private fun hideFab(view: View){ 
    view?.rvHome?.addOnScrollListener(object : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener(){
        // all other
    }
}
```

and call it from `onCreateView`:

```
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)
    
    hideFab(view)     /// <--- View here

    return view
}
```

2. Or, just call `hideFab()` from `onViewCreated` callback of the Fragment

Answer (score 0):

I like to handle this with an FAB Behavior class.

```
// Since the class is called from XML it will need a context and attribute in the constructor. 
class FABBehavior(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : FloatingActionButton.Behavior() {

    /**
     * Called when the user starts scrolling though the player list.
     */
    override fun onStartNestedScroll(
        coordinatorLayout: CoordinatorLayout,
        child: FloatingActionButton,
        directTargetChild: View,
        target: View,
        axes: Int,
        type: Int
    ): Boolean {
        return if (axes == ViewCompat.SCROLL_AXIS_VERTICAL) {
            true
        } else {
            super.onStartNestedScroll(
                coordinatorLayout,
                child,
                directTargetChild,
                target,
                axes,
                type
            )
        }
    }

    /**
     * Called When user is scrolling through the list.
     */
    override fun onNestedScroll(
        coordinatorLayout: CoordinatorLayout,
        child: FloatingActionButton,
        target: View,
        dxConsumed: Int,
        dyConsumed: Int,
        dxUnconsumed: Int,
        dyUnconsumed: Int,
        type: Int,
        consumed: IntArray
    ) {
        super.onNestedScroll(
            coordinatorLayout,
            child,
            target,
            dxConsumed,
            dyConsumed,
            dxUnconsumed,
            dyUnconsumed,
            type,
            consumed
        )

        // This statement will hide the Fab on a downward swipe and make the fab visible on an upward
        // swipe.
        if (dyConsumed > 0 && child.visibility == View.VISIBLE) {
            child.hide(object : FloatingActionButton.OnVisibilityChangedListener() {
                override fun onHidden(fab: FloatingActionButton) {
                    super.onHidden(fab)
                    fab.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
                }
            })
        } else if (dyConsumed < 0 && child.visibility != View.VISIBLE) {
            child.show()
        }
    }
}
```

Add the behavior to the FAB XML

```
<coordinatorlayout>
        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/my_fab"
            ...
            app:layout_behavior=".playerlist.ui.FABBehavior"/>
<coordinatorlayout/>
```